# Where is the OpenCart mail class request?

Tags: php, opencart

In the "account/register.php" controller file, when a new account gets created, where is the command to send an email to the user?

I couldn't find it anywhere, not in the controller file and not in the model file.

What am I missing?

Same with the account/forgotten.php controller, couldn't find what sends the reset mail.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at controllers that handles emails, they are located are upload_folder/catalog/controller/mail

Comment: @Triby tried to take a look at those controllers, but couldn't find the code that runs those controllers. It must be somewhere...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenCart 3 doesn't explicitly call the mail controller as you'd expect. Instead there are a number of pre-defined "events" that trigger certain controller actions.

You can see the list of Events being loaded into memory on the file `catalog\controller\startup\event.php` here it calls `getEvents()`. These events are registered in memory with a corresponding controller action that is performed when the event is triggered (usually before or after a function is called).

So looking at your question, you can't explicitly "see" the code where the function is called. What you can see is the mail controller itself and the respective extensions "forgot", "register" etc. You can also view the list of events directly in the database by looking at the contents of the `oc_event` table

For example, the action triggered by a customer registering on the website is called `mail_customer_add` the trigger is `catalog/model/account/customer/addCustomer/after` i.e. after the `addCustomer` function is called successfully and the action that is triggered is `mail/register`.

Similarly, the action triggered by a customer resetting their pass on the website is called `mail_forgotten` the trigger is `catalog/model/account/customer/editCode/after` i.e. after the `editCode` function is called successfully and the action that is triggered is `mail/forgotten`.

What is it that you're actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Very detailed answer, thank you very much, it helped me a lot.
Since OpenCart is an open source software Im tweaking it to behave just like I want (for example, "ajaxifying" all of the forms) and therefore I need to handle the mailing system a bit differently.

Comment: You're welcome @AlonPini. May I suggest that you spend some time learning / familiarising yourself with the OCMOD system? My approach has been to create a local site, use GIT to track changes that I make and then turn the list of staged files into the OCMOD XML format. It'll make your life much easier down the line.

Comment: I've heavily modified the core of OC so Im aftaid OCMOD won't react well with the modifications that I've made, but I surely will take a look. I'm a sort of a newbie at coding, so I don't recognize some of the terms you mentioned, but I will google it to see if it might make things easier as you say :)